# Question about interchanging series and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

How can I reason the following interchange of integral and series:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(t)e^{-itx}dt=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(t)e^{-itx}dt$$

Because $e^{-itx}$ can get smaller than $0$, I can't use Fubini.

Comment: The series converges uniformly, so it is ok to integrate it term-by-term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interchange because:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{2^n}< \infty$$

So from $DCT$ you have the desired conclusion.

Comment: Are you using the following theorem: For general $f_n$, if $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$ or $\sum \int |f_n| < \infty$ (by Tonelli the two conditions are equivalent), then $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$ where $f_n:=\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(t)e^{-itx}$?

Comment: If not, what are our $f_n$, $f$ and $g$ in my example in the noation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: I use the following: If $\sum \int |f_n| < +\infty$ where $f_n$ are integrable functions, then we can interchange the sum and integration, from domitated convergence